# How to detect DMG application is m1 compatible from bash?

Tags: command-line

I want to check macOS app compatibility with apple silicon cpu from command line.

It could be `intel`, `apple-silicon` or `universal`.

Comment: You'll probably have to look inside the DMG image to reliably detect this.

Comment: I know. I looking for exact file and field value.